# Method called twice instead of single call in Dask's multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I am trying to download a file from google storage bucket and parse them. There are millions of such file, that needs to be downloaded, parsed and do some operations(Natural language processing etc) on them.

I am trying below code using dask's parallel processing and it is working but it is calling `extract_skill` twice instead of once for each row in panda's dataframe. Please help me understand why `extract_skill` method is being called twice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

# downloading file and extract skill sets and store in skill_sets column
chunk_size = 20
df_list = np.array_split(temp_df, temp_df.shape[0]/chunk_size)
temp_df["skill_sets"] = ""
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data={}, columns=temp_df.columns)

for df_ in df_list:
    df_["skill_sets"] =  dd.from_pandas(df_, npartitions=4, sort=False, name='x').apply(extract_skill, axis=1, meta='object').compute()
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, df_], axis=0)
```

**extract_skill()**

```
def extract_skill(row):
    // download file, parse and do some nlp stuff
    file_name = row['file_path']
    ......
    ......
    return skill_sets
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataFrame.apply` method runs your function on a small sample of data in order to determine the datatypes and columns of the output.  See the docstring of this function and look for the keyword "meta" for more information.